# Need to write some text on PDF document

Tags: iphone, ipad

In my iPad application i need to write some text on PDF document.
like "Doc Sign" application.

do anyone have any idea ?
is there any library for that ?

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can Open a PDF and draw it a CALayer ([Example](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/196313-display-pdf-in-calayer.html)) or UIImage ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831304/calayer-and-off-screen-rendering/3853778#3853778)) then do your doc signing then draw the PDF back to a context ([Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) ref:Listing 13-4)

Answer (score 0):

Look at Apple's [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/adding_custom_graphics_to_a_pdf?language=objc) for answers on how to draw on or create annotations on a PDF page.